# Should tag "15" be removed?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Should the tag "15" be removed?

or, at least made synonymous with "2013"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is we don't yet know what the final product name of SharePoint 15/SharePoint 2013 will be. Perhaps neither. I suspect that if we merge the tags someone will create the other one again, but we could try.

Comment: There are only 4 organic uses of the 15 tag (see my comment on TimeToThine's answer), and all in conjunction with 2013. I think it can be safely burninated.